# How cast any to method signature on typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins, rxjs

I want to cast an any to a method signature on TypeScript.

I am using RxJs and a cordova's plugin that has an event. This event has an "any" signature, so when i bind it with "bindCallback", i cannot put my parameteres.

The following code works, but is working without observable pattern:

```
this.map.on((<any>window).plugin.google.maps.event.CAMERA_CHANGE, () => {
try {
  console.log('it works!!');
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

I think with observable pattern would to be something like this:

```
let eventAsObservable = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(this.map.on);
let result = eventAsObservable((<any>window).plugin.google.maps.event.CAMERA_CHANGE);
result.subscribe(x => console.log('don't work --> ' + JSON.stringify(x)));
```

My problem is that "eventAsObservable" don't accept parameters. I think it's because "this.map.on" is marked as any.

So, would be great if i can cast "any" to a method that accepts a numeric or string parameter signature.

How can i solved it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changin this

```
let eventAsObservable = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(this.map.on);
```

To this

```
let eventAsObservable = Rx.Observable.bindCallback(<(a: number) => any>this.map.on);
```

Works for me